# C# SerialPort read response bytes after request

Tags: c#, .net-core, serial-port

Based on this example: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28968 I'm writing app to communicate with device over serial port, based on protocol document.
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TN10
{
    public class TN10
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(ResponseData().Result));
        }

        public static async Task<byte[]> GetResponseData()
        {
            byte[] hextosend = {0x06, 0x30, 0x30};
            var bytestosend = SendReceive.GetBytesToSend(hextosend);
            var timeout = new TimeSpan(1000000000);

            var sendTask = Task.Run(() => new PortChat().SendMessage(bytestosend, timeout));
            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAny(sendTask, Task.Delay(timeout));
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }

            var response = await sendTask;
            return response;
        }

        public static async Task<byte[]> ResponseData()
        {
            var data = await GetResponseData();
            return data;
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in ba)
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            return hex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace TN10
{
    public class PortChat
    {
        private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();
        public SerialPort Port = new SerialPort(new Config().ComPort, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        public byte[] SendMessage(byte[] message, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            // Use stopwatch to update SerialPort.ReadTimeout and SerialPort.WriteTimeout 
            // as we go.
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            // Organize critical section for logical operations using some standard .NET tool.
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                var originalWriteTimeout = Port.WriteTimeout;
                var originalReadTimeout = Port.ReadTimeout;
                try
                {
                    // Start logical request.
                    Port.WriteTimeout = (int) Math.Max((timeout - stopwatch.Elapsed).TotalMilliseconds, 0);
                    Port.Open();
                    Port.Write(message, 0, message.Length);

                    // Expected response length. Look for the constant value from 
                    // the device communication protocol specification or extract 
                    // from the response header (first response bytes) if there is 
                    // any specified in the protocol.
                    var count = 17;
                    var buffer = new byte[count];
                    var offset = 0;
                    // Loop until we recieve a full response.
                    while (count > 0)
                    {
                        Port.ReadTimeout = (int) Math.Max((timeout - stopwatch.Elapsed).TotalMilliseconds, 0);
                        var readCount = Port.Read(buffer, offset, count);
                        offset += readCount;
                        count -= readCount;
                    }

                    return buffer;
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Restore SerialPort state.
                    Port.ReadTimeout = originalReadTimeout;
                    Port.WriteTimeout = originalWriteTimeout;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is the code simply does not return bytes read from port.
I see them if I put breakpoint on this line

> var readCount = Port.Read(buffer, offset, count);

but nothing "after".
Thanks.

Comment: The code is waiting until you get 17 bytes.  If you get less than 17 it just sits in the while loop.

Comment: Thank You. I was getting 8 bytes but 17 is max for some other request sequence.

Comment: When you send a message you need to include where the message terminates.  With ASCII you can include a character not part of the message like a "\n".  Then when you get a "\n" you can exit out of the loop.  You can send a byte count at beginning of message and then on receive end read byte count and exit while loop after you get the correct number of bytes.

Comment: Use `ReadByte` if you don't want to block. If you want to always get full response with blocking, use `Read` with determined count, not "possible maximum count".